# XMLSerializer returning string as null after saving it itself

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, inotifypropertychanged

I am having a class with a string and a list that gets populated by the words in my string. When saved everything looks fine and the programm is working fine. The XML file also looks fine.

However, once i reload my programm and therefore load from the XML file i get a "string = null" error. Here is my class:

```
public class Wortarten : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Wortarten(string quest)
    {
        strLatein = quest;
    }

    public Wortarten()
    { }

    private string _strLatein;
    public string strLatein { set { this._strLatein = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("listLatein"); } get { return this._strLatein; } }

    private List<string> _listLatein = new List<string>();
    public List<string> listLatein 
    { 
        set 
        { 
            this._listLatein = value;
        } 
        get 
        {
            _listLatein.Clear();
            string[] sep = new string[] { " ", ", " };
            string[] lWorte = strLatein.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string wort in lWorte)
            {
                _listLatein.Add(wort);
            }
            return _listLatein;
        } 
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And here is the raw data in the XML-File.

```
   <Wortarten>
    <strLatein>Wort1, Wort2, Wort3, Wort4, Wort5.</strLatein>
    <listLatein>
      <string>Wort1</string>
      <string>Wort2</string>
      <string>Wort3</string>
      <string>Wort4</string>
      <string>Wort5.</string>
    </listLatein>
  </Wortarten>
```

The exact error is a simple: "strLatein null".

So, why is strLatein null here? Any idea on where i screwed up?
Edit: The error shows up in this line, but ONLY on XMLLoad, while adding the values in my running programm it is working without an error. Therefore the XMLSave saves the right values,...:

```
string[] lWorte = strLatein.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Please note that my programm has 3 more classes and everything is working fine. The loading and saving has been working for several weeks. Only this new class seems to have this issue, i do however not have any other classes that implement iNotifyPropertyChanged. So it is very possible that it is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't serialize the list. It's just redundant data. Further, properties shouldn't behave as data generators unlike methods.

Comment: I agree on the redundant data thing. No optimization pass done yet. Removing the list from serialization did not solve the problem tho. The exact same error shows up, obviously the strLatein variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider serializing and de-serializing using a markup language like XML or JSON, and then storing your text to a file. It could make your job a lot easier. Serialization and de-serialization can also greatly help you be extensible for the future as well. It makes adding more variables to your objects very easy.

Here is an example for XML serialization using a simple car object:

```
public void WriteFile(Car testCar)
{
    string path = "c:\temp\testCarPath.xml";
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);

    serializer.Serialize(file, testCar);
    file.Close();
}

public Car ReadFile()
{
    Car testCar;
    string path = "c:\temp\testCarPath.xml";
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    testCar = (Car)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();

    return testCar;
}
```

Comment: Uhm, that is exactly what i do. Using XMLSerializer. The problem is the StreamReader part, it just returns null for a string that it saved itself just a second before.